# Only two 2GB memory available on 64-bit Linux kernel

Tags: debian, 64bit

I've just upgraded my Debian Linux (Wheezy) to a 64 bit kernel, as well as user mode binaries, in an attempt to make use of the 4GB of memory in the system without PAE.

Exchanging the kernel and packages seems to have gone fine, but I'm not getting the expected result:

```
mymachine:~# dmesg | grep Memory
[    0.000000] Memory: 2007644k/2062784k available (3494k kernel code, 452k absent,
                       54688k reserved, 3042k data, 476k init)

mymachine:~# uname -m
x86_64
```

What could be causing this? I would like to expand the memory further, but if I can't even make use of the current 4GB, that is a bit useless :)

`lshw` output says shows the memory is properly installed:

```
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 29
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: PartNum0
         vendor: Manufacturer0
         physical id: 0
         serial: SerNum0
         slot: DIMM A1
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: PartNum1
         vendor: Manufacturer1
         physical id: 1
         serial: SerNum1
         slot: DIMM B1
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

The Memory Remap Feature is enabled in my BIOS.

Comment: This seems very odd to me, since I've installed linux on various 64-bit 4 GB machines and there has never a problem with memory, using either either stock distro kernels or ones I built myself, going back at least to 2.6.x.  Do you have a reasonably modern live CD handy? Try booting that -- if you still don't get all of it, something is definitely weird; post the first ten lines of `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Can you see the 4G with the PAE kernel?

Comment: You don't happen to have some extra stuff in kernel commandline like `mem` or `memmap`, that would change it's behaviour, do you?

Comment: "I've just upgraded my Debian Linux (Wheezy) to a 64 bit kernel". This sentence concerns me. Did you try to upgrade from Squeezy or Wheezy 32 bits to 64 bits? Because if that was what you did... you better reinstall your system. Not only for this memory issue but for all 32 bits packages messing up your system and its stability.

Comment: @yZT: The system upgrade went fine. It takes some time to fix some of the packages, but nothing serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your motherboard apparently only supports 2GB or is buggy.  See the bios e820 section of the kernel boot messages for exactly what memory your bios is telling the kernel it has.

Comment: Close enough... for some reason the motherboard doesn't seem to like this set of DIMMs. I tried different ones and they worked fine. Running with 8GB now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a hardware failure; at least that was the reason when I had such a problem.

- That hardware failure wasn't reported as a failure, nothing suspecious in kernel (linux 4.15 x64 on ubuntu) log.
- `lshw` (and Windows in dual boot) reported 4Gb RAM installed, 2 Gb x 2

But `free -m` as well as task manager in Windows showed only 2 Gb as available RAM, BIOS-e820 also reported:

```
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000784cefff] usable
```

(this is a 2 Gb interval)

Hardware: if plugged separately, one by one, first DIMM gives 2 Gb total memory, another one: 0 Gb.

Cleaning DIMM RAM contacts was the solution :)

**Happy end:** After cleaning and inserting back the system again I had 4 Gb.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. It would be interesting to know if you only had 2 Gb of your installed 4 Gb available from the very beginning, or if originally you had 4 Gb available and at some point the available RAM suddenly dropped to 2 Gb (was it a degradation of the contacts over time, or already bad contacts when the RAM modules were installed).

Comment: I was helping a friend of mine. He states that initially OS saw all 4 Gb, so the problem probably the contacts degradation.